# How to cover code for SOQL and if statement in Apex class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Can any one please help me to how to cover those SOQL and if Condition?

Answer (score 2):

You need tp update your survey reocrd to  match the condiitons

```
survey__c survey = new survey__c(Contact__c = con.id, Most_Recent_NPS_Survey__c  = true);
Insert survey;
```

And need to provide same contact id in task as well

```
Task task= new task();
     task.Subject='Message Sent';
    task.status='Completed';
    //task.Whatid= survey.id;
    task.whoId = con.id;
    insert task;
```

It will cover your if conditions.

Also you should use system.assert in your test class to validate your functionality.
Something like

```
System.assert(task.Whatid == survey.Id)
```

Comment: survey__c survey = new survey__c(Contact__c = con.id, Most_Recent_NPS_Survey__c  = true);
Insert survey;   In this line firing error like "Field is not writeable: Survey__c.Most_Recent_NPS_Survey__c"

Comment: @chris I think it's a formula field. In this case you need to set this formula field to true

Comment: Yeah you are right, But already set that field true as your answer (passed parameter). Should i set values to all fields in formula field or what?

Comment: @chris as this is a formula field so you need to set the condition by which this  formula will return true. for eg: if your foumal field check parentId not blank then yu need to populate parentId so that formula will return true. we can't directly set formula field value.